# copying files using `ncp` throws: no such file or directory, mkdir

Tags: node.js, glob, fs-extra

I'm using `ncp` to copy files as following:

```
import ncp from "ncp";
import { promisify } from "util";

const ncpPromise = promisify(ncp);
const copyAssets = async (exportFolderName, includeSourceMaps) => {
  const assets = glob.sync("**/", { cwd: distPath });
  const options = { clobber: true, stopOnErr: true };
  if (!includeSourceMaps) {
    options.filter = (f) => {
      return !f.endsWith(".map");
    };
  }
  return Promise.all(
    assets.map((asset) => {
      return ncpPromise(
        path.join(distPath, asset),
        path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName, asset),
        options
      );
    })
  );
};
```

But this sometimes fails with the following error:

```
"ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/path/to/folder'"
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: @raina77ow Could you please check my post edit, it's from this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/util.promisify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to copy all files matching for the given glob, so you need to do:

```
const assets = glob.sync("**/*.*", { cwd: distPath }); // note the *.*
```

For example, your current glob in question will result into:

```
[
  'folder1/',
  'folder2/',
]
```

whereas the glob in this answer will result into (This is what you want):

```
[
  'folder1/file1.txt',
  'folder1/file2.txt',
  'folder2/anotherfile.txt',
]
```

---

#### An Alternative:

Seems like [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) isn't being maintained. So, you can use [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), it can copy file and directory as well:

```
const glob = require("glob");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const copyAssets = async (exportFolderName, includeSourceMaps) => {
  const assets = glob.sync("**/*.*", { cwd: distPath });

  const options = { overwrite: true };

  if (!includeSourceMaps) {
    options.filter = (f) => {
      return !f.endsWith(".map");
    };
  }

  return Promise.all(
    assets.map((asset) => {
      return fs
        .copy(
          path.join(distPath, asset),
          path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName, asset),
          options
        )
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that but the error message got changed to `"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/file'"` (notice `open` on the file instead of `mkdir`), the path here is inside the export folder and not where I'm copying files from.

Comment: The error with `open` means the destination directory doesn't exist. I would suggest that you use `fs-extra` as written in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

NPM [qir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qir) (*yes, it is published by myself*) is another choice:

```js
const qir = require('qir');
qir.asyncing.copy('/A/path/to/src', '/B/path/to/dest')
    .then(() => { /* OK */ }
    .catch(ex => { /* Something wrong */ }
    ;
```

Here, **/A/path/to/src** may be a file or a folder, and **/B/path/to** is not required to exist already.

There is a synchronous way:

```js
const qir = require('qir');
qir.syncing.copy('/A/path/to/src', '/B/path/to/dest');
```

And, if both **src** and **dest** located in the same directory:

```js
const qir = require('qir');
let q = new qir.AsyncDir('/current/working/dir');
q.copy('A/path/to/src', 'B/path/to/dest')
    .then(() => { /* OK */ }
    .catch(ex => { /* Something wrong */ }
    ;
```

It will copy **/current/working/dir/A/path/to/src** to **/current/working/dir/B/path/to/dest**.

Comment: If gir is published by yourself, you should disclose your affiliation in your answer.

Comment: It's OK and I have edited my answer. BTW, the name of the package is __qir__ instead of __gir__.